# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException Unparseable date

Tags: java, exception, gson, date-formatting

I am getting following exception -

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 04/03/2017 10:39:55.000
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
```

I have set the date format as -

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").create();
```

And I don't have control on the date format. How can I setup GsonBuilder to handle **2 different time formats** so that the above exception can be avoided?

EDIT - In another instance the Time will appear as `04/03/2017 10:39:55 AM` That's why I need to handle 2 different time formats.

Comment: Your expected date format does not match your actual date. `.setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")` is enough to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format that you supplied (`"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"`) does not match the date format of your input (`04/03/2017 10:39:55.000`). Your input has milliseconds after the seconds, and no AM/PM notation. Correct dateformat is:

```
setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
```